# Migration Magento1.9.4 to Magento 2.3.0 Setting command after error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool, magento-1.9.4.0

When I run **migration command**

`sudo php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset`

> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.0/config.xml

after below error showing..

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'principal' for key 'STORE_GROUP_CODE'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please perform following steps and run `migrate:settings` command after that, and do let me know if you get any issue.

```
Go to to this Directory "{your_root_directory}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.0/"
Rename file config.xml.dist to config.xml (remove .dist from end)
Rename file map.xml.dist to map.xml (remove .dist from end)
```

**-- UPDATE --**

**Magento 2 has new field 'code' in store_group table and it is automatically created from magento 1 store name.**

**So it seems you have a duplicate store name in magento 1**

**Please do change your store name "principal" to anything from your magento 1 database**

Please let me know if you get any issue after that.

Comment: i have allready try this but still not working

Comment: obviously i have rename this file

Comment: yes right..........

Comment: let me check and update you

Comment: i have added your code in map.xml but same error showing

Comment: **Can you, who downvoted, please explain your reasoning**

Comment: i have not downvoted

Comment: no which one  query?

Comment: what do you mean this query mate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90307/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-aasim-goriya).

Comment: @AasimGoriya, I need to migrate only products and customers, can we skip orders?

Answer (score 0):

Add this entry to ignore file in migration config `principal`.
and run again, it will work.

All these table names and fields which are not "standard" need to be either ignored or mapped in your version of the `map.xml.dist` configuration files.

add this line:

```
 <source>
      <field_rules>
        <ignore>
          <field>store_group.code</field>
        </ignore>

      <ignore>
           <field>store_group.group_id</field>
       </ignore>
<ignore>
           <field>store_group.website_id</field>
       </ignore>
<ignore>
           <field>store_group.name_id</field>
       </ignore>
<ignore>
           <field>store_group.root_category_id</field>
       </ignore>
<ignore>
           <field>store_group.default_store_id</field>
       </ignore>
```

Or you can add tables to ignore like this:

```
<ignore>
  <document>core_config_data</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
  <document>store_group</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
  <document>store</document>
</ignore>
 <ignore>
  <document>store_website</document>
</ignore>
```

for more info go to Magento 2 documentation.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

Comment: edit my answer, just look

Comment: if i  think add your code then migration not successfully not  done

Comment: you have mysql error , that says : you have duplicated value principal in STORE_GROUP table in field - CODE, just ignore it, or edit.

Comment: where but i have just setup and run settings command

Comment: thats why you can ignore tables/fields that i have described above.

Comment: but i think this tables skip when migration ao i have not used your idea